# iPhone CoreData: How to group fetched results by day?

Tags: iphone, date, core-data, group-by

I am developing an iPhone App with CoreData. One of my entities has an NSDate property named 'time'. It stores times to the minute/second. As my sections i'd like to have the date to the day. So if there are to entries '2010-06-14 8:00' and '2010-06-14 11:00', i'd like them to be grouped to '2010-06-14'.

Currently I just use @"time" as my sectionNameKeyPath:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
    initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
    sectionNameKeyPath:@"time"
    cacheName:@"Root"];
```

Is there a trick to group by the time to the day? Or do I have to use plain SQL and something like "`GROUP BY date(time, '%Y-%m-%d')`"?

Answer (score 15):

Solved it this way:

Added method `- (NSString *)day;` to my Entity class with an implementation like this:

```
- (NSString *)day {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.time];
}
```

Then I used `@"day"` as `sectionNameKeyPath` in the initialization of `aFetchedResultsController` instead of `@"time"` (see above).

Comment: Just wondering: why not return a string with `self.time.components.day`?

Comment: Also doesn't the overridden getter disappear when you re-generate the `NSManagedObject` subclass for your entity?

Comment: @Matt typically a method like this will be in a category of the entity, to avoid that problem.